# Server 2012 Internet printing - no connect button

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, printing

I have a Windows Server 2012 with Print Services installed and IPP (Internet Printing) enabled.

I can get to the page http://PrintServer/Printers without issue, but there is no connect button.

All of the other buttons are shown and can be clicked. I've tried IE11, Firefox, Chrome, and messed with the compatibility settings

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Also, the connection doesn't show on the server when I browse to the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

If the Internet Explorer security is set to high, the Connect link on the Web management page for that printer is not displayed. This prevents users from connecting to the printer through the Web page. Please change the Internet Explorer security for test.

You also need to install the Internet Printing Client on the client machines and then restart the printer spooler service.  After that, the Connect button will show up when accessing to the IPP.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, this does not work on IE11. IE10 seemed to show that button fine though. Can you try a machine with IE10 just to confirm?

Comment: Just to check - make sure that the IPP client is installed on your OS as well. By default, it should be installed under Programs and Features.

Comment: I'll try on an IE10 machine and let you know.  Also, I installed the IPP client as a feature on the server, is that what you meant ?

Comment: Something else I noticed. I currently have a Server 2008 R2 with IPP enabled and IE11 w/compatibility mode on can use it without any issues. I think this is a new issue with Server 2012.

Comment: Okay, we tried accessing the page with an IE10 client and still no connect button.